# How to install npm lame raspberry pi 0

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi, lame

I'm trying to install `npm lame` on a raspberry pi 0. I've googled everything but keep getting this error:

Not really sure what else to do.

```js
pi@raspberrypi:~/twotone $ sudo npm install lame

> lame@1.2.4 install /home/pi/twotone/node_modules/lame
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/10.15.0"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/home/pi/twotone/node_modules/lame/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/pi/twotone/node_modules/lame/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.14.79+
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/twotone/node_modules/lame
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN twotone@1.0.0 No description

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! lame@1.2.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the lame@1.2.4 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-01-06T22_12_04_380Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Sounds like a permission error with the user you're using - `mkdir '/home/pi/twotone/node_modules/lame/.node-gyp'`

Comment: Yea, but every other npm module I installed worked fine, and I'm running sudo. How can I get around this? There isn't even a `lame` directory

Comment: you might have to add `--unsafe-perm` to the npm install command

Comment: that worked. thanks @vicatcu

Comment: great, i'll add it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to add --unsafe-perm to the npm install command